# C++ trying to convert command lines to int. Get segmentation Fault when using atof() or atoi()

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm building an Extensible Hashing structure, and I need to use two command line arguments:

A - Bucket size in bytes (integer).
B - Number of fields of the register (integer).

I need to convert these two arguments to `int` to use in my program. I tried to use atof() or atoi(). The program compiles and run without any errors, but when I debug it I get a Segmentation Fault, and I can't see where am I wrong.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int size = atoi(argv[1]);
    int campos = atoi(argv[2]);
}
```

I get the segmentation fault on `int campos = atoi(argv[2]);`

I would prefer not to post the entire code here as it is greater than 200 lines.
Comands used to build and run:
    g++ hash.cpp -o hash
    .\hash 5000 250

Comment: If the code is too long then post a [mcve].

Comment: Which arguments are given to the program?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that `argc` is at least 3 before extracting the numbers from the command line arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if(argc < 3) {
     cerr << "Not enough command line arguments!\n";
     return 1;
  }
  int size = atoi(argv[1]);
  int campos = atoi(argv[2]);
}
```

Comment: Im using the following instructios: g++ hash.cpp -o hash .\hash 5000 250 so argc in this case should be == 3 and yet the segmentation fault

Comment: @LucasCastro Add that information into your question please.

Answer (score 0):

`argv[0]` is name of program 
`argv[1]` -> first argument 
`argv[2]` -> second argument

You should check for this and make sure it's correct.

Comment: Im using the following instructios:
g++ hash.cpp -o hash
.\hash 5000 250

Answer (score 0):

I were using VSCode and the Debbuger's launch.jason file were not setted to use comand line argmuments. There is no errors in the code. Thank you all for the support.
To solve just add on launch.jason file the comand line arguments needed at the Debbuger configuration:
        "args": [arg1, arg2, ..., argn],

Answer (score -1):

atoi is the C-style way to convert strings to integers. Use boost::lexical_cast to do that. It is safe and throws an exception if the cast is bad.

Comment: No need for `boost::lexical_cast` actually.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you explain why or others ways to do this?

Comment: @LucasCastro It probably won't change anything to get rid of your problem, and including `boost` to your application sounds like total overkill for me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok, thanks for the support, it seems like i found and solved the problem

Comment: @LucasCastro If you found and solved your problem you should write an answer here please.